# UITextView scroll to bottom without animation

Tags: uiscrollview, uitextview

I want the UITextView to show the last text so I did

```
[self.textBox scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([self.textBox.text length], 0) ];
```

However, I don't want the scrolling action since it will start from the very top and scroll down each time I enter in a new line of text.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

`UITextView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, so you can call the latter's methods directly on it.

```
CGPoint offsetPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, textView.contentSize.height - textView.bounds.size.height);
[textView setContentOffset:offsetPoint animated:NO];
```

P.S. In your question you wrote `UITextField`, but it was clear from your description and code that you meant `UITextView`. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: thank you for the edit and response! I just tried it, however it doesn't seem to scroll down by itself/go to the last line

Comment: also, I did change textView to self.textBox when I added it to my code

Comment: Does nothing whatsoever happen?

Comment: unfortunately, no, it doesn't automatically scroll to the last (bottom) inserted line

Comment: I know what it *doesn't* do. I'm asking what, if anything, it *does* do. Do you get identical behaviour with or without the [self.textBox setContentOffset:offsetPoint animated:NO] line?

Comment: Nope it doesn't do anything, but I do get an error saying that using various CGgeometry is a fatal error

Comment: When I scroll to the bottom to show the last line entered, then enter another line, the UITextView scrolls back to the top automatically when I press enter

Comment: "Using Various CGGeometry Is A Fatal Error" doesn't turn up anything in a google search: are you sure you got the text of that error message exactly right? ;)

Comment: I'm searching for the same thing. Tried this solution and the text view doesn't scroll at all :(